# my drop down menu have event queue please stop it

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new in jquery help me to solve my problem

i create a drop down menu but it have a event queue problem please tell me how to solve this and it have a one more problem

if some one click quickly in buttons so some time two divs drop down

but it needed only one div drop down if any one click quickly in buttons

sorry for my bad english

**jquery**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button2').click(function() {
    $('.buy-now,.About-Product,.kgn-tech').slideUp(150, function() {
      $('.Product-Image').slideDown(900, function() {
        $(".button1,.button3,.button4").css({
          "background-color": "#f5f5f5",
          "font-size": "14px",
          "border-bottom-color": "#d8d8d8",
          "color": "#666"
        });
        $(".button2").css({
          "background-color": "#ececec",
          "font-size": "15px",
          "border-bottom-color": "#ececec",
          "color": "#333333"
        });
      });
    });
  });

  $('.button3').click(function() {
    $('.buy-now,.Product-Image,.kgn-tech').slideUp(150, function() {
      $('.About-Product').slideDown(900, function() {
        $(".button2,.button1,.button4").css({
          "background-color": "#f5f5f5",
          "font-size": "14px",
          "border-bottom-color": "#d8d8d8",
          "color": "#666"
        });
        $(".button3").css({
          "background-color": "#ececec",
          "font-size": "15px",
          "border-bottom-color": "#ececec",
          "color": "#333333"
        });
      });
    });
  });

  $('.button4').click(function() {
    $('.buy-now,.Product-Image,.About-Product').slideUp(150, function() {
      $('.kgn-tech').slideDown(900, function() {
        $(".button3,.button1,.button2").css({
          "background-color": "#f5f5f5",
          "font-size": "14px",
          "border-bottom-color": "#d8d8d8",
          "color": "#666"
        });
        $(".button4").css({
          "background-color": "#ececec",
          "font-size": "15px",
          "border-bottom-color": "#ececec",
          "color": "#333333"
        });
      });
    });
  });

  $('.button1').click(function() {
    $('.kgn-tech,.Product-Image,.About-Product').slideUp(150, function() {
      $('.buy-now').slideDown(900, function() {
        $(".button4,.button2,.button3").css({
          "background-color": "#f5f5f5",
          "font-size": "14px",
          "border-bottom-color": "#d8d8d8",
          "color": "#666"
        });
        $(".button1").css({
          "background-color": "#ececec",
          "font-size": "15px",
          "border-bottom-color": "#ececec",
          "color": "#333333"
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.button2,
.button3,
.button4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 31px;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buy-now {
  background-color: #ececec;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px -1px;
}

.button1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #ececec;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 31px;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  border-bottom-color: #ececec;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #ececec !important;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  color: #333333 !important;
}

.button2:hover {
  background-color: #ececec !important;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  color: #333333 !important;
}

.button3:hover {
  background-color: #ececec !important;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  color: #333333 !important;
}

.button4:hover {
  background-color: #ececec !important;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  color: #333333 !important;
}

.Product-Image {
  background-color: #ececec;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px -1px;
}

.About-Product {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px -1px;
}

.kgn-tech {
  background-color: green;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px -1px;
}

**html**
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="button-div-mein">
    <div class="button">
      <input type="button" class="button1" value="Buy Now" onclick="#">
      <input type="button" class="button2" value="Product Image" onclick="#">
      <input type="button" class="button3" value="About Product" onclick="#">
      <input type="button" class="button4" value="Kgn Tech" onclick="#">
    </div>
    <div class="buy-now"></div>
    <div class="Product-Image"></div>
    <div class="About-Product"></div>
    <div class="kgn-tech"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try to use [`stop`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the previews animation. But at first, please rid the repetition code. For example, instead of add event listener for each button, you can listen only for `$('button')` and check which `div` is currently visible, hide it, and display the one who you want to display.

Comment: thanx bro you are really good man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactors a little your code to avoid code repetition. You can read more about the functions I used on jQuery website.

The logic is:

1. When any button (tab) click, check if it in middle of animation. If it does, ignore the click (we will "release" this lock once the animation will over).
2. Get the panel you should display from `data-panel` attribute. (For more info about [`[data-*]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attributes)
3. Add `active` class to clicked button (set the style in the `css` instead of in the code) and remove from all his [`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
4. slideUp the [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) panel.
5. Slidedown the panel you want to display.
6. "Unlock" the `inAnimation` flag.

And all this in the code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var inAnimation = false;
  $('.button').click(function() {
    if (inAnimation) {
      return;
    }
    inAnimation = true;
    var $this = $(this),
        panelToShow = $('.' + $this.data('panel'));
    
    $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('.panel:visible').slideUp(150, function() {
      panelToShow.slideDown(900, function() {
        inAnimation = false;
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #ececec;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 31px;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  border-bottom-color: #ececec;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #ececec !important;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  color: #333333 !important;
}

.button.active {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom-color: #d8d8d8;
  color: #666;
}

.buy-now {
  background-color: #ececec;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px -1px;
}

.product-image {
  background-color: #ececec;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px -1px;
}

.about-product {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px -1px;
}

.kgn-tech {
  background-color: green;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px -1px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="button-div-mein">
    <div class="buttons">
      <input type="button" class="button active" value="Buy Now" data-panel="buy-now">
      <input type="button" class="button" value="Product Image" data-panel="product-image">
      <input type="button" class="button" value="About Product" data-panel="about-product">
      <input type="button" class="button" value="Kgn Tech" data-panel="kgn-tech">
    </div>
    <div class="panel buy-now"></div>
    <div class="panel product-image"></div>
    <div class="panel about-product"></div>
    <div class="panel kgn-tech"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My pleasure :) If it answer your question, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/303669) the answer so it will help to other people.. Good luck!

Comment: ok done (i am new in stackoverflow.com , i want know is there any option like:follow or add friend)

Comment: All good, welcome aboard :) The voting and the accepting answers are meant to tell the users if that answer is answering the question (from point of view of the OP) and how much it's helpful for another users (so it most of the change will help to the current user too). It's very important for the quality of this website and that's why it's THE WEBSITE FOR Q&A ;)